# How do Japanese people say "bed" as in the physical bed?

Tags: words

My textbook (JFZ series) gives the word bed as ベッド which makes sense as the western bed (on legs) wouldn't have existed in Japan a long time ago.

The dictionary also gives 床 and 寝.

I presume young people say ベッド, if not please correct me.

What would old people call a western bed ?

All related info welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean physical bed, then it's always ベッド.

床{とこ} is only used in idioms like 床に就く meaning *go to bed*. 寝 should be mentioned similarly because *go to bed* can be translated as 寝る. 寝 itself means more *to sleep* than furniture for sleeping.

Comment: So would old people also all say ベッド ? Would they ever call it anything else ?

Comment: @Kantura Yes. Suppose someone is 100 years old now. S/he was 22 yo when the war was over. This means s/he spent most of her/his life in Japan where more or less American culture is dominant. It's fairly unlikely s/he doesn't know the word ベッド. Anything else is wrong as a word to refer to Western beds. SImply older people don't sleep in bed. They use futon.

Comment: There's [寝台](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%AF%9D%E5%8F%B0/#je-37873), but it usually means a bed in trains.

Comment: It is interesting to note here that a surprisingly large amount of people, in all ages, will say ベット instead of ベッド, even though the former strictly speaking means "bet".

Comment: @a20 I could be wrong, but it seems to me that it's unusual in native Japanese words to have a sokuon followed by a voiced consonant. So they may just find it awkward or unfamiliar to pronounce.